# Xamarin locally loading JS script

Tags: javascript, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am very new to Xamarin.
I am struggling to load a JS file which is embedded in my app.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>iOS WebView</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" />

</head>
<body>
<h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1>

<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
<button onclick="test1()">Test 1</button>

<img src="XamarinLogo.png" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function test1() {
        alert('1');
    }

</script>
```

Function test() is in test.js and it is in the resource folder with default.css and XamarinLogo.png. It is strange because the latter 2 files are loaded.

Clicking the first button never fires the alert but the second one does because the function is in the html.

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Comment: According to your code It's no problem . Maybe you can try set all your file in one root folder ,and in html you can write `button` method after write `script`.

Comment: Thanks @johnheaven the problem was with the build action on the resource JS.

Comment: Yeah, your solution will be helful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out.
The problem was with the properties and how the external JS was linking to the main html page.

In the JS file properties set the 'build action' to 'BundleResource' and the 'Resource ID' to 'test.js' or whatever.
Hope this helps someone.